# Dúvida de soma de vetores e gravação no banco

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tenho esse formulário simples

```
<form>
    <div class="itenspedido">
                <h4>Itens do Pedido</h4>
                    <div id="itens">
                                    <div class="div-bloco-form">
                                        <label class="obrigatorio">Quantidade:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="$Quantidade"/>
                                    </div>
                    </div>
           </div>
 </form>
```

aqui o formulário será clonado

```
<script>
                    function adicionar() {
                        var itm = document.getElementById("itens").getElementsByClassName("div-bloco-form")[0];
                        var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
                        var inputs = cln.getElementsByTagName("input");

                        for (i = 0; i <= inputs.length - 1; i++) {
                            if (inputs[i].type === "text")
                                inputs[i].value = "";
                        }

                        document.getElementById("itens").appendChild(cln);
                    }

                    function remover(btn) {
                        var div = btn.parentNode;

                        if (numLinhas() > 1)
                            div.remove();
                    }

                    function numLinhas() {
                        var linhas = document.getElementById("itens").getElementsByClassName("div-bloco-form");
                        return linhas.length;
                    }

                    </script>
```

Agora a seguinte dúvida, conforme irei clicando no botão para clonar o formulário. Gostaria no final gravar no banco, todos os forms. 
Eu entendo a lógica que será de 1 para N. Porém o uso de for ou foreach que acredito que seja isso que eu preciso usar ainda não sei como fazer.
Sou iniciante, preciso de uma ajuda e agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que está no seu código hoje a função clona o campo quantidade dentro do form, para ser incluído vários valores diferentes nesse campo, não faz muito sentido isso ter vários inputs de quantidade (não está clonando o form) mas se for isso mesmo que você quer é só você trocar o name do input para um array assim `<input type="text" name="Quantidade[]"/>` e recuperar os valores por post (se o seu form vá ser passado por post `<form method="post">`) testando com `json_encode($_POST['Quantidade'])`, você terá os valores em array ex: ["3","4"] onde foram incluídos valores 3 e 4 nos dois inputs criados no form.
e para recuperar e inserir cada valor:

```
   while (list ($chave, $valor) = each ($_POST))    {
        if ($chave == "Quantidade") {
            foreach ($valor as $value) {
                //insert que será criado onde $value contém o valor digitado em cada input
            }
        }
    }
```

ou você pode:

na sua função adicionar coloque dentro do for, além de criar com valor nulo os inputs, mude o name acrescentando números na frente assim `inputs[i].name =inputs[i].name + numLinhas();` e para pegar depois no post você pode usar um for pegando valores dos posts assim `$_POST['Quantidade'.$i]` onde o $i seria os campos clonados 1, 2 e assim por diante

Comment: É que no caso eu quis resumir o formulário para não ficar um código longo. Nele contem o Nome do produto, quantidade, valor unitário e total.

Comment: Entendi editei minha resposta acrescentando código que poderia utilizar para mudar o name dos campos acrescentandos números para recuperar no post dentro de um for com a quantidade de registros clonados.

Comment: for (inputs[i].name = 0; inputs[i].name + numLinhas();) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "text")
         inputs[i].value = "";
       }   seria isso?

Comment: for (i = 0; i <= inputs.length - 1; i++) { 
                            if (inputs[i].type === "text")
                                inputs[i].value = "";inputs[i].name =inputs[i].name + numLinhas();
                        }

Comment: é o mesmo for e if que você já tem só acrescentar no if além do inputs[i].value="" também o inputs[i].name = inputs[i].name + numLinhas();

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Solange, vou tentar isso então.